# WordPress: How can I disable Gravity Forms inclusion of jQuery?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, gravity-forms-plugin

I am including jQuery already on my website, but when using some conditional logic with Gravity Forms, it includes jQuery again, as well as its own scripts of course.

Output looks like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//localhost:8080/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//localhost:8080/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//localhost:8080/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/jquery.json.js?ver=1.9.14'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//localhost:8080/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/gravityforms.min.js?ver=1.9.14'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//localhost:8080/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/conditional_logic.min.js?ver=1.9.14'></script>
```

What I would like to do is to keep the Gravity Form's scripts, but exclude their inclusion of **jQuery** and **jQuery migrate**. I include these myself and do not want GF to do this for me.

I have searched for the handle that includes these scripts, but cannot find the correct hook. I had the following, but it also excluded the GF scripts, which is obviously not what I want to happen:

```
function remove_unwanted_assets() {

    // Gravity Forms plugin.
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_unwanted_assets', 100);
```

This seems to exclude everything from GF.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like Gravity Forms is including `jquery.json.js`...not `jquery.js`...at least according to the code you shared. The other jQuery is the default jQuery that is included with WordPress (i.e. the one you should be using anyways)

Comment: Maybe so, but doing wp_deregister_script('jquery'); excludes the GF scripts too. Not sure why! Or how to get jQuery excluded and not affect GF.

Comment: No idea why my question is being down voted. Absolutely no sense. I provided a problem, an attempted solution and full code examples. Mind boggling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to reliably "deregister" the default jQuery is to keep the priority of your `add_action()` call at `10`. This is because Gravity Forms enqueues scripts with a priority of `11`. You'll then need to register your own version of jQuery under the same handle:

```
function so_33280386_alter_assets() {
    // De-register the default version of jQuery
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    // Register a new version of jQuery under the same handle
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', false, '1.9.1', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_33280386_alter_assets', 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to accomplish the same thing and I found a simple workaround. I am adding jQuery in my own compiled js file so I don't want WordPress's file in there. Simply deregister the script and then re-register it without add a source.

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

wp_register_script( 'jquery', '', '', '', true );
```

I also am using a few other snippets in order to keep ajax loading loading correctly.

```
function gravity_js_to_footer() {
    return true;
}
add_filter("gform_init_scripts_footer", "gravity_js_to_footer");



// Fix the ajax jquery inline code issue when gravity js is being called in the footer
//https://bjornjohansen.no/load-gravity-forms-js-in-footer
add_filter( 'gform_cdata_open', 'wrap_gform_cdata_open' );
function wrap_gform_cdata_open( $content = '' ) {
    $content = 'document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() { ';
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'gform_cdata_close', 'wrap_gform_cdata_close' );
function wrap_gform_cdata_close( $content = '' ) {
    $content = ' }, false );';
    return $content;
}
```

With these things combined I am able to not call enqueue jquery and also have everything in the footer.

Good Luck